# wx.DestroyChildren in event handler cause segmentation fault on osx

Tags: python, macos, segmentation-fault, wxpython

The following Python code runs fine on windows, but cause a segmentation fault on
osx. Any suggestions why? It does not make a difference to use CallAfter...

```
import wx

class myFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Static text'))
        self.sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, -1, 'Button'))
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

    def on_button(self, event):
        self.sizer.Clear()
        self.DestroyChildren()

app = wx.App()
frame = myFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Have you tried pinpointing the line that causes the segfault ?

Comment: Yes, it is DestroyChildren. Tried wx.CallAfter(self.DestroyChildren) too with same result.

Answer (score 0):

It is because there are still system messages pending for the destroyed widgets, (mouse motion in this case) as well as the possibility that the code that is run after the return from the event handler will try to use the destroyed widgets (calling methods or accessing attributes.)

Using CallAfter to delay the destruction does solve the problem for me, which version of wxPython are you using?  If this doesn't work for you then you may want to try using wx.CallLater instead, with a small timeout value.

```
import wx 

class myFrame(wx.Frame): 
    def __init__(self): 
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None) 
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
        self.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'Static text')) 
        self.sizer.Add(wx.Button(self, -1, 'Button')) 
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer) 
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button) 

    def on_button(self, event): 
        wx.CallAfter(self.doit)

    def doit(self):
        self.sizer.Clear() 
        self.DestroyChildren() 

app = wx.App() 
frame = myFrame() 
frame.Show() 
app.MainLoop()
```